# Adapting CS50's Resize (less comfortable) to Resize (more comfortable)?

Tags: c, image-resizing, cs50, bmp

I've been reading through a couple posts with this same question, but most seem to have gone about the easier problem differently than I did, so I'm having trouble finding tips on how to proceed.

Without posting my code, (not sure if we can do that here or not), the pseudo code for the main resizing portion was kind of like this:

```
for each scanline
{
    for number of times to extend vertically
    {
        for each pixel in infile
        {
            read pixel from infile

            for number of times to extend horizontally
            {
                write pixel
            }
        }
        done extending horizontally, add padding to outfile
        move cursor to front of line
    }
    done extending vertically, move to next line by passing padding
}
```

Maybe my nested loops aren't that quick or elegant, but it was the first logic train that came to me and it worked out. Nonetheless, I'm pretty unsure of how to adapt this for floating point numbers and the fact that I need to shrink things now.

I'm aware I'll have to do some sort of rounding. If I have only one pixel and the user tells the program to resize it by .5, I'll still give them one pixel because I can't tear apart the bytes that make it up. Similarly, whenever I upscale, I'll presumably always give full pixels.

But where do I start with this logic? How do I decide what the "scale" is and how will it interact with my loops? I can't loop something 1.5 times, so I imagine I'll have to know what the rounded scale is prior to going into the loops. I can't even begin to think about shrinking something this way... I'd probably have to skip over certain pixels in the loop in order to do that? Seems like a totally different mechanism that could mess up the resulting image.

Anyways, any help is appreciated!

Comment: There are 3 different algoritms, depending on the resize factor: factor > 1 (you provided the pseudo-code already), factor < 1 (another algorithm) and factor == 1 (do nothing, you already have the correct size).